# MarkLogic Semantic Sparql

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to query semantic content in a MarkLogic database using Query Console, with **MINUS** in the query. QC shows an error like this:

> XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected , expecting }

The error highlights the **MINUS** keyword. The SPARQL Query standard supports **MINUS**, so why is there an error?

Answer (score 2):

Full SPARQL 1.1, including MINUS, is on MarkLogic's roadmap and will be available in a release coming soon. MINUS is not supported as of 8.0-3.